# Split a record by record type and report any unexpected record type

Tags: text-processing, scripting

I have a `myfile.txt` that contains several record types.
The record type is at position 27, with length of 3 chars, like this:

```
12345678901234567890123456E20XXXXXXXXX
12345678901234567890123456I47XXXXXXXXX
12345678901234567890123456I49XXXXXXXXX
12345678901234567890123456I50XXXXXXXXX
12345678901234567890123456W55XXXXXXXXX
12345678901234567890123456E20XXXXXXXXX
12345678901234567890123456I47XXXXXXXXX
12345678901234567890123456Q11XXXXXXXXX
12345678901234567890123456R11XXXXXXXXX
12345678901234567890123456W55XXXXXXXXX
12345678901234567890123456E20XXXXXXXXX
12345678901234567890123456I47XXXXXXXXX
12345678901234567890123456I49XXXXXXXXX
12345678901234567890123456I50XXXXXXXXX
12345678901234567890123456Q11XXXXXXXXX
12345678901234567890123456R11XXXXXXXXX
12345678901234567890123456W55XXXXXXXXX
```

I would like to split it by record type, like this:

```
grep -E '^.{26}(E20)' myfile.txt > E20.txt
grep -E '^.{26}(I47)' myfile.txt > I47.txt
grep -E '^.{26}(I49)' myfile.txt > I49.txt
grep -E '^.{26}(I50)' myfile.txt > I50.txt
grep -E '^.{26}(Q11)' myfile.txt > Q11.txt
grep -E '^.{26}(R11)' myfile.txt > R11.txt
grep -E '^.{26}(W55)' myfile.txt > W55.txt
```

and do something else, for example

```
echo "Unexpected record type"
```

when the record type is not in (E20, I47, I49, I50, Q11, R11, W55).

For example, `E20.txt` file will be:

```
12345678901234567890123456E20XXXXXXXXX
12345678901234567890123456E20XXXXXXXXX
12345678901234567890123456E20XXXXXXXXX
```

and so on.

Is there an elegant way to do it (in a script) on Linux?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one `awk` way. First, create a file with the "good" records, one per line:

```
$ cat goodRecs 
E20
I47
I49
I50
Q11
R11
W55
```

Then:

```
gawk 'FNR==NR{good[$1]; next} 
     { 
        rec=substr($1,27,3); 
        if(rec in good){
            print > rec".txt"
        }
        else{
            print "Bad record: "rec
        }
    }' goodRecs myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

Using any awk and any sort:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
    BEGIN {
        split("E20 I47 I49 I50 Q11 R11 W55",tmp)
        for ( i in tmp ) {
            expected[tmp[i]]
        }
    }
    {
        type = substr($0,27,3)
        if ( type in expected ) {
            print type, NR, $0
        }
        else {
            printf "%s[%d]: Unexpected record type \"%s\"\n", FILENAME, FNR, type | "cat>&2"
        }
    }
' "${@:--}" |
sort -k1,1 -k2,2n |
awk '
    $1 != prev {
        close(out)
        out = $1 ".txt"
        prev = $1
    }
    { print $3 > out }
'
```

```
$ ./tst.sh myfile.txt
```

```
$ head [A-Z]*.txt
==> E20.txt <==
12345678901234567890123456E20XXXXXXXXX
12345678901234567890123456E20XXXXXXXXX
12345678901234567890123456E20XXXXXXXXX

==> I47.txt <==
12345678901234567890123456I47XXXXXXXXX
12345678901234567890123456I47XXXXXXXXX
12345678901234567890123456I47XXXXXXXXX

==> I49.txt <==
12345678901234567890123456I49XXXXXXXXX
12345678901234567890123456I49XXXXXXXXX

==> I50.txt <==
12345678901234567890123456I50XXXXXXXXX
12345678901234567890123456I50XXXXXXXXX

==> Q11.txt <==
12345678901234567890123456Q11XXXXXXXXX
12345678901234567890123456Q11XXXXXXXXX

==> R11.txt <==
12345678901234567890123456R11XXXXXXXXX
12345678901234567890123456R11XXXXXXXXX

==> W55.txt <==
12345678901234567890123456W55XXXXXXXXX
12345678901234567890123456W55XXXXXXXXX
12345678901234567890123456W55XXXXXXXXX
```

The above uses the [DSU (Decorate/Sort/Undecorate) idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71691113/how-to-sort-data-based-on-the-value-of-a-column-for-part-multiple-lines-of-a-f/71694367#71694367) to make the script very efficient, robust and portable while retaining input order for duplicate keys.

Answer (score 1):

A bash (or POSIX shell) version

```
#! /bin/sh

exec < "$1"

while read aline
do  key=${aline:26:3}
    case $key in 
    E20|I47|I49|I50|Q11|R11|W55)
        echo $aline >> $key.txt;;
    *)  echo "${0##/} Unexpected record '$key' encounterd" 1>&2;;
    esac
done
```

Run this with:

```
sh program-name input-file-name
```

Use bash if /bin/sh is not capable.